# Using Data Annotations for SQLite in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I am using the Entity Framework Core to interface my SQLite database. I want to set a minimum and maximum range for the field `ExitSide` in my model `Station`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
...
class Station
{
    public int StationId { get; set; }
    [Range(0,2)]
    public int ExitSide { get; set; }
}
```

But somehow it seems to get ignored. I am still able to create `Stations` with `ExitSide=5` for example. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be like ` [Range(0,2)]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core does not currently recognise the Range data annotation